# Cannot import FileOpener into my app.module.ts

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4, fileopener2

As written in the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener), to import FileOpener you should place

```
import { FileOpener } from "@ionic-native/file-opener";
```

in you app.module.ts, but always get "Invalid provider in ngModule..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the right path to import FileOpener is

```
import { FileOpener } from "@ionic-native/file-opener/ngx";
```

That's looking in the plugin source file

Comment: Thank you. I had the same problem. It's a shame the documentation is so bad.

Comment: @Leia Thats true they havnt given in the documentation, how to import modules.